# How to create a option menu in android?

Tags: c#, android, menu, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to create a simple option menu in Android application with c# and Xamarin Studio. How can I do it?

I haven't found any C# example of this. Can someone simply explain how to create a option menu, please?

Comment: I think that after a couple edits, this is a real and valid question. Why not reopen it?

Comment: Agree, actually I found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## **Defining the menu**

One way to create a menu is using a XML file placed in the Resources/menu/ folder of your Xamarin.Android project.

For example:

**Resources/Menu/mymenu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 3"/>
</menu>
```

To see what other options you can define in a menu xml file, please see [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

## **Using the menu**

You can inflate a xml menu in multiple locations.
A few examples:

### **In a Toolbar**

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.mytoolbar);
toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.mymenu);
```

**Handle clicks**

To handle click events on a toolbar menu you  have to implement the `Toolbar.IOnMenuItemClickListener` interface by overriding the following method:

```
public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.item1: 
                //Do stuff for item1
                return true;
        case Resource.Id.item2: 
                //Do stuff for item2
                return true;
        case Resource.Id.item3:
                //Do stuff for item3
                return true;
        default:
                return false;
     }
}
```

You then have to add the class implementing the interface to the toolbar as a listener:

```
toolbar.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(your_listener_class);
```

### **In the default menu location of an Activity or Fragment (DEPRECATED)**

In most cases the default menu location of an activity or fragment is either the hardware menu button or the ActionBar.
Adding a menu here can be accomplished by the overriding the following method:

**In a Activity:**

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**In a Fragment:**

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.mymenu, menu);
}
```

Make sure you have `HasOptionsMenu` set to true in the onCreate of the Fragment for this to work.

**Handle clicks**

You can then handle clicks to the menu by overriding `OnOptionsItemSelected`

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
       case Resource.Id.item1: 
                //Do stuff for item1
                return true;
        case Resource.Id.item2: 
                //Do stuff for item2
                return true;
        case Resource.Id.item3:
                //Do stuff for item3
                return true;
        default:
                return false;
     }
}
```

After we have handled the selected item we return true to notify the system of this.

## **Alternative: Creating a menu programatically**

A very basic menu is accomplished by overriding the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` method like this:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
      menu.Add(0,0,0,"Item 0");
      menu.Add(0,1,1,"Item 1");
      menu.Add(0,2,2,"Item 2");
      return true;
}
```

You can then handle clicks in the option menu by overriding the `OnOptionsItemSelected` method.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case 0: 
                //Do stuff for item 0
                return true;
        case 1: 
                 //Do stuff for item 1
                return true;
        case 2: 
                //Do stuff for item 2
                return true;
        default:
                return false;
     }
}
```