# Error while creating Menu Dynamically with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need to Create a menu dynamically in my application developped with Xamarin Android. 
For that I wrote this code:

```
 public  class MyActivity : Activity
    {

        private static readonly int DRTC = Menu.First;
        private static readonly int DRR = Menu.First + 1;
           protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_my);


        }
  public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            bool result = base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            menu.Add(0, DRTC, 0, "Modify TC");
            menu.Add(0, DRR, 0, "Restart DR");

            return result;
        }
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
            case Resource.Id.DRTC: //ERROR
        //Code
         Break;
             case Resource.Id.DRR://ERROR
        //Code
             Break;
             bool result = base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return result;
}
}
```

The error says that Resource.Id doesn not contain a definition for DRTC and DRR.
Can you please see what am I missing in this code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public  class MyActivity : Activity
    {

        private const int DRTC = 0;
        private const int DRR = 1;
           protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_my);


        }
  public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            bool result = base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            menu.Add(0, DRTC, 0, "Modify TC");
            menu.Add(0, DRR, 0, "Restart DR");

            return result;
        }
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
            case  DRTC: 
        //Code
         Break;
             case  DRR:
        //Code
             Break;
             bool result = base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return result;
}
}
```

And take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224150/how-to-create-a-option-menu-in-android)